# Add custom fields while add/edit wordpress category

Tags: wordpress

I am using **WP-3.5.1** and want to know how can we add more custom fields (image, radio, check-box, drop-down) while adding/editing category?

I found http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields but first here author did not mention

> Where to add his code?
>
> For which version of wp this code be use?
>
> What affect if we upgrade to latest version?
>
> What must be pass `extra_category_fields( $tag )` in?

so I start from **wp-admin/edit-tags.php** and paste his code right after where **Slug** field is defined but stuck on **$tag** what should be pass here?

Is there any plugin to add custom fields in category like **More Field** which is for posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, there is a big red warning in that page:
[image]

So, clearly, you'd better use the new version.

Second, you should **never** modify core files (`/wp-admin/edit-tags.php`). The following Q&A explains where you should put code enhancements in your WordPress site:
[**Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

*Restore your core files to its original state using the [following instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update)*.

Try to always use the *latest version* of WordPress, Themes and Plugins, as having old code in your site may have serious security/performance implications.

The new version of *Taxonomy Extra Fields* has much more examples in its documentation, so probably your configuration doubts would change.

All that said, the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) is able to put extra fields in Taxonomies (categories, tags, custom taxonomies) very easily, no coding required.

Comment: Thanks buddy and after more deep search I found http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/categories-images/

Answer (score 0):

Okay:

To add image filed while add/edit category use this plugin it is awesome plugin.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/categories-images/